# sm.ols(endog = y, exog = x) will not run even though I'm just considering two arrays

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a linear regression summary from the dose and the consumption variables by using the sm.ols(y, x) formula, but for whatever reason it's not allowing me to do so even though I've seen it work in countless examples. Any suggestions will be appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hThnp.png)

I tried using sm.ols(endog = y, exog = x) but a TypeError came up that sm.ols() is miissing 2 positional arguments 'formula' and 'data'. I understand how those may apply if I'm importing my data from a csv file, but I'm just trying to access basic arrays.

Comment: Please include enough of your code to reproduce your problem and the complete text of the error message you received.

Comment: Also have you imported statsmodels.formula.api?

Comment: Please include your code and the error message in your question as text and not as a link to an image.